# Inverting a Map[Long, Set[Long]) to a Map[Long, Long]

Tags: scala

Trying to convert a `Map[Long, Set[Long]]` to a `Map[Long, Long]`.

I tried this but having compile issues:

```
m.map(_.swap).map(k => k._1.map((_, k._2)))
```

Example:

```
Map(10 -> Set(1,2,3), 11 -> Set(4,5))
```

Should become:

```
Map(1 -> 10,
    2 -> 10,
    3 -> 10,
    4 -> 11,
    5 -> 11)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What should be the keys and values in the result map?

Comment: Each value should be a key, and the value of that key is the key. I'll update my Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `in` is your `Map[Long, Set[Long]]`:

```
in./:(Map.empty[Long, Long]) { case (acc, (key, values)) => acc ++ values.map(_ -> key) }
```

Answer (score 3):

`flatMap` on `Map[A,B]` will "just work" with collections of tuples:

```
m.flatMap {case (k,v) => v.map(_ -> k)} // Map[Long,Long]
```

going from a `Map[Long,Set[Long]]` to a series of `Set[(Long,Long)]` that gets flattened to a `Map[Long,Long]`.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, seem like you have this:

```
Map(10 -> Set(1,2,3), 11 -> Set(4,5))
```

And you want to convert this map in another map, but with something like this:

```
Map(1 -> 10,
    2 -> 10,
    3 -> 10,
    4 -> 11,
    5 -> 11)
```

As you can see if the sets are not disjoint, some keys in the resulted map with be missing:

Having this in consideration, the code will look like this:

```
val m: Map[Long, Set[Long]] = Map(10l -> Set(1l,2l,3l), 11l -> Set(4l,5l))

m.map(_.swap).map(k => k._1.map((_, k._2)))

val foo: Iterable[(Long, Long)] = m.flatMap { t =>
  val (key, value) = t
  value.map(_ -> key)
}

val result: Map[Long, Long] = foo.toMap
```

Comment: how will a key be missing?

Comment: Just try the same example with this map: Map(10l -> Set(1l,2l,3l,4l), 11l -> Set(4l,5l)) it's because on a Map you can't have repeated keys..

Comment: the values are guaranteed to be unique.  so there won't be a value that will point to the same key.

Comment: Then this solution is safe!

Answer (score 1):

This will invert your `Map` `m` from `Map[Long, Set[Long]]` to `Map[Long, List[Long]]`.

```
m flatten {case(k, vs) => vs.map((_, k))} groupBy (_._1) mapValues {_.map(_._2)}
```

You haven't specified what should happen when different `Set` values contains some of the same `Long`s (i.e. `Map(8 -> Set(1,2), 9 -> Set(2,3))`). If you're sure that won't happen you can use the following adjustment.

```
m flatten {case(k, vs) => vs.map((_, k))} groupBy (_._1) mapValues {_.head._2}
```

Or even more simply:

```
m.flatten {case(k, vs) => vs.map((_, k))}.toMap
```

Comment: it won't happen, the values are all unique and won't ever point to the same key.  The result has to be a Map[Long, Long] not a Map[Long, List[Long]]